# PySpark Pivot Single Column, Multiple Aggregates

Tags: python, pyspark, pivot, transpose

I want to take a dataframe with an hour column and pivot it accordingly:

```
+----+----------+---------+---------+
| Day|Identity X|Feature A|Feature B|
+----+----------+---------+---------+
|  01|         0|       44|        3|
|  01|         1|       20|        1|
|  02|         0|       33|        3|
|  02|         1|       55|        5|
|  03|         0|       94|        5|
|  03|         1|       10|        1|
+----+----------+---------+---------+

+------------+--+--+--+
|.  Feat\Day |01|02|03|
+------------+--+--+--+
|        AvgA|32|44|52|
|        AvgB| 2| 4| 3|
+------------+--+--+--+
```

I can't find anything efficient for this in PySpark alone. I had been grouping by a F.lit('A') and then taking an average of each feature, and then concatenating, but that is clearly pretty inefficient even at the small scale I'm working at.

I had seen previous posts for using koalas to .transpose() the dataframe, however I'm looking for a more general purpose solution, especially for cases when I want to aggregate over other columns. I can group by and aggregate on multiple columns, but then I'll have 6 columns instead of the 3 listed here.

Answer (score 1):

you can first get the means, and then unpivot the resulting dataframe. the unpivoted data will help in transforming it to the desired result.

here's an example

```py
data_sdf. \
    groupBy('day'). \
    agg(func.mean('feat_a').alias('avg_a'), 
        func.mean('feat_b').alias('avg_b')
        ). \
    withColumn('attr', 
               func.array(*[func.struct(func.lit(c).alias('c_name'), func.col(c).alias('c_val'))
                            for c in ['avg_a', 'avg_b']]
                          )
               ). \
    selectExpr('day', 'inline(attr)'). \
    groupBy('c_name'). \
    pivot('day'). \
    agg(func.first('c_val')). \
    show()

# +------+----+----+----+
# |c_name|  01|  02|  03|
# +------+----+----+----+
# | avg_a|32.0|44.0|52.0|
# | avg_b| 2.0| 4.0| 3.0|
# +------+----+----+----+
```

---

`attr` field is an array of structs that contains the column name and column value. this helps in the unpivot which is done using the `inline` SQL function (it explodes the array and unpacks the structs).